# Table is not creating using JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

I am using JPA 2.0 in Netbeans. I am using entities. If my database has no table then it should create table from entities. Here is my code

```
public class BankServlet extends HttpServlet {

     @EJB
     private BankServiceBeanRemote bankServiceBean;

     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

        int custId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        bankServiceBean.createCustomers();
        Customer cust = bankServiceBean.findCustomer(custId);

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        ....

    } //end of processRequest

} //end of class BankServlet
```

Here is my bean

```
@Stateless
public class BankServiceBean implements BankServiceBeanRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Bank_JPA-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void createCustomers() {

        Referee r1 = new Referee();
        r1.setId(1);
        r1.setName("SIR JOHN DEED");
        r1.setComments("JUDGE");     
        em.persist(r1);

        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.setId(1);
        c1.setFirstName("SIMON");
        c1.setLastName("KING");
        c1.setReferee(r1);

        ......
    }

} //end of class BankServiceBean
```

Here is my referee entity

```
@Entity
public class Referee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String comments;

    public Referee() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // other getter setters

} //end of class Referee
```

When i run the code i get following exception

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table     'dbbank.referee' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: INSERT INTO REFEREE (ID, NAME, COMMENTS) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3, MICHAEL ELLIS, MAJOR SHAREHOLDER OF THIS BANK]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(pk.mazars.basitMahmood.entity.Referee[id=3])
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
```

If table doesnot exist then it should create table automatically. Am i doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong. Tables are not magically created if they don't exist. Most of the applications use existing databases.

EclipseLink *can* create the schema for you, but it's not the default. Read [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL) to know how to enable this feature:

> EclipseLink can be used to automatically generate the tables and
>   database schema for a persistence unit. This is done through the
>   "eclipselink.ddl-generation" persistence unit property, set to either
>   "create-tables" or "drop-and-create-tables". The tables and
>   constraints will be generated for all of the classes defined in that
>   persistence unit.

Comment: hhmm so if i have a database,l ike i created a database named dbbank in mysql using netbeans. Then i created an entity and link it with the dbbank database. Now i have database and the entity is linked with it. Now the persistence API create the table automatically for me ?

Comment: Only if you tell EclipseLink to create the database tables for you. Read the link I gave you. It's all explained there.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your table generation strategy in persistence.xml.

just add these rows to the persistence.xml file :

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet to add to your persistence.xml to make **openjpa** create tables for you. This comes in handy when doing in container unit tests using openejb with an in memory database like HyperSQL.

```
    <properties>
         <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
    </properties>
```